# How to get the application's ProductName in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to programmatically get the ProductName of a Silverlight application? I'm looking for the Silverlight equivalent of this WinForms/WPF instruction:

```
string productName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following method, but only if you can guarantee that you call it from the "entry" assembly.

```
public static void GetProductAndVersionEasy(out string productName, out Version productVersion)
{
  var callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

  // Get the product name from the AssemblyProductAttribute.
  //   Usually defined in AssemblyInfo.cs as: [assembly: AssemblyProduct("Hello World Product")]
  var assemblyProductAttribute = ((AssemblyProductAttribute[])callingAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyProductAttribute),false)).Single();
  productName = assemblyProductAttribute.Product;

  // Get the product version from the assembly by using its AssemblyName.
  productVersion = new AssemblyName(callingAssembly.FullName).Version;
}
```

(You can replace GetCallingAssembly with GetExecutingAssembly if the method is in your entry assembly).

I also figured out how to **hack** this information from the .xap file. I load the main assembly's bytes into memory, then read the product and version info from the last few bytes. I had to write this because I needed a method I could reuse in a base library which can be called from anywhere (ie. not the executing or calling assembly).

```
public static void GetProductAndVersionHack(
  out string productName, 
  out Version productVersion)
{
  // Get the name of the entry assembly
  var deployment = System.Windows.Deployment.Current;
  var entryPointAssembly = deployment.EntryPointAssembly + ".dll";

  // Get the assembly stream from the xap file
  StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(
    new Uri(
      entryPointAssembly, 
      UriKind.Relative));
  Stream stream = streamResourceInfo.Stream;

  // The VERSION_INFO struct as at the end of the file. Just read the last 1000 bytes or so from the stream
  // (Keep in mind that there are a lot of zeroes padded at the end of the stream. You should probably
  //  search for the real stream.Length after trimming them off)
  stream.Position = stream.Length - 1000; 
  StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
  string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

  // Split the string on the NULL character
  string[] strings = text.Split(
    new[] { '\0' }, 
    System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  // Get the Product Name (starts with unicode character \u0001)
  int ixProductName = strings.FindIndexOf(line => line.EndsWith("\u0001ProductName"));
  productName = ixProductName >= 0 ? strings[ixProductName + 1] : null;

  // Get the Product Version
  int ixProductVersion = strings.FindIndexOf(line => line.EndsWith("\u0001ProductVersion"));
  productVersion = ixProductVersion >= 0 ? Version.Parse(strings[ixProductVersion + 1]) : null;
}

public static int FindIndexOf<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> source, 
  Func<T, bool> match)
{
  int i = -1;
  foreach (var item in source)
  {
    ++i;
    if (match(item)) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Oops, I only notice now that I used one of my extension methods 'FindIndexOf' in the second code sample. I'll be happy to share its code on request.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what device your deving for, but for WP7 silverlight, In the Properties folder contained a file called WMAppManifest.xml, and under Deployment>App their is a field called Title, you can pull the XML out of there?

I hope that helps.

Comment: No I'm not using WP7..I've checked and there's no such file in my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The AssemblyName class provides parsing of the Assembly FullName property.

Try this

```
string productName = (new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(this.GetType().Assembly.FullName)).Name;
```